# Hide all references to Science Fiction and Games

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

On the the right hand side of stackoverflow.com I see "Hot Network Questions" column.  I would like to eliminate any Science Fiction or Game related question from that column and anywhere else I might see them while browsing stackoverflow.com.

I would like to take this action once and not have to maintain a list or words.

I am okay with seeing topics about programming games, but I am willing to not see topics about programming games if I can eliminate seeing anything about games.

I am also okay with just turning off that entire "Hot Network Questions" column if that is the only place where I am likely to stumble on Science Fiction and Game related questions.

I am not anti-science fiction or anti-game, it is just confusing because some of the questions sound real and are intriguing, then I read the question to find out it is some game.  I don't feel compelled to memorize all the icons so I can tell which ones to ignore.

Comment: In the meantime, you could make a userscript that would handle this for you.

Comment: There's some great practical advice in those gaming questions, though, like http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41636/i-want-a-divorce-whats-the-most-painless-way-of-obtaining-one :)